# 'he prepared the design' or 'he designed'?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Here are my constructions:

> 1. While carrying out his engineering project, **he prepared the design
>      of** wired and wireless network infrastructure and developed the new architectural plans of the building.
> 2. While carrying out his engineering project, **he designed** wired and
>      wireless network infrastructure and developed the new architectural plans of the building.

So my question is, should I use 'he prepared the design' or 'he designed'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. *While carrying out his engineering project, he prepared the design of wired and wireless network infrastructure and developed the new*
>      *architectural plans of the building.*

Comparing the noun and verb definitions of design, the expression *prepared the design* tends to limit his participation to **the drawing** aspect of the project:

> *[design](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/design)*
>
> noun
>
> 1.0 A plan or drawing produced to show the look and function or workings
>   of a building, garment, or other object before it is made:
>
> *[design](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/design)*
>
> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1.0 Decide upon the look and functioning of (a building, garment, or other object), by making a detailed drawing of it:
>
> 1.1 Do or plan (something) with a specific purpose in mind:
>
> ODO

The sentence below, can denote the same meaning, but it can also suggest his design involvement in **wired and wireless infrastructure** was deeper than just drawings for this building:

> 2. *While carrying out his engineering project, he designed wired and wireless network infrastructure and developed the new architectural*
>      *plans of the building.*

The broader meaning is reinforced by an omitted determiner. Adding another *the* would suggest his *design activity* was limited to the specific architectural plans of the building, as opposed to a broader development of wired and wireless network infrastructure:

> 3. *While carrying out his engineering project, he designed **the** wired and wireless network infrastructure and developed the new architectural*
>      *plans of the building.*

If the intention is to credit the man for broader development of wired and wireless network infrastructure, it might read more smoothly as:

> 4. *While carrying out his engineering project, he designed **wireless and wired** network infrastructure and developed the new architectural*
>      *plans of the building.*

Comment: Dueling dictionaries: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/design) has
**design** 5a :  an underlying scheme that governs functioning, developing, or unfolding :  pattern, motif,  *the general design of the epic*, which certainly goes well beyond blueprints. For architecture, I'd agree that *design* usually means *drawing*, but definitely not for networks.